# Is SCOPE_IDENTITY() relevant to the session or to the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reason for using @@identity rather than scope_identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353526/reason-for-using-identity-rather-than-scope-identity)

When a user adds a record to a table, I want to return the ID of that record to be used in the pages following the insert. I'm currently using this command (see example):

```
INSERT INTO tCRnames (fname, lname) VALUES ('Super','Man')
DECLARE @Id INT;
SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
SELECT @Id;
```

I have two questions regarding this method.

1. Is this command relevant to the session? Meaning if two users insert a record at exactly that same time, will there be a problem with the returned ID's?
2. Is there a better way to return the inserted ID? Currently all my ID's are normal identity fields, which is fine; but we are thinking of making some changes to some of our services which will leave us with ID fields that are NOT identity fields.

You will then get a generated ID such as "TMP001-05" or just "000004".

How do I return the inserted ID from that insert(besides from returning it upon generation)?

Comment: How are you going to generate the new ID values? You won't use `IDENTITY` columns anymore, right?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I did, hence my comment asking to clarify things - the 2nd part of the question should be a **separate question**.

Comment: @marek My reading suggests that it *is* the crux of the question. The first is just a lead in.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi There are 5 answers at the moment and only 2 of them refer to the 2nd part of the question, so I still think that the question could be worded better.

Answer (score 1):

1. scope_identity() is for the session
2. use [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, which will get the ids post-trigger, if you have one that manipulates/creates ids

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the way you are doing it is the "best" way and will return the ID of INSERTed row *from this current transaction*.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

> **SCOPE_IDENTITY** and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in ***any table in the current session***. However, **SCOPE_IDENTITY** returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

Answer (score 0):

Its relevent to the current session+current statement

Answer (score 0):

1. The value is local to the session, so there is no problem if different users add records at the same time.
2. If the id is not automatically generated then you create it yourself, so it would be easiest to just hang on to that value. You can also use `output` to get the values from the inserted records, as RichardTheKiwi suggested.